# Laravel. Возможно ли создать один процесс для всех запросов?

Tags: laravel

Есть внешний сервис, к которому нужно делать много запросов. Однако, количество соединений с ним ограничено, и требуется сделать нечто вроде прокси: слать запросы курлом в рамках одного http соединения (например, с временем жизни "Keep-Alive: timeout=60").

Как бы это сделать на Laravel? На ум приходят сокеты, но я не знаю, как к ним такое прикрутить.

Comment: Для работы с сокетами требуется, чтобы и внешний сервис принимал данные через WS. У вас уже есть какие-то наработки? Что вообще за задача? Может подойдет вариант очереди задач (queues)?

Comment: Дочитайте статью до конца) "Если используете PHP — возьмите нашу библиотеку, создайте один раз объект DadataClient и переиспользуйте его — так новые соединения не будут создаваться."

Comment: Задача: выдавать подсказки для введённого адреса через сервис Dadata. То есть, пользователь отправляет get запрос контроллеру, дальше МАГИЯ, а в конце это сообщение уходит сервису дадаты. Ну и возвращается ответ.
Вот здесь описание, почему нельзя создавать отдельные запросы:
https://support.dadata.ru/ru/knowledge-bases/4/articles/8875-ogranichenie-na-kolichestvo-novyih-soedinenij
Очереди - не знаю, может быть.

Comment: "создайте один раз объект DadataClient и переиспользуйте его" - я не знаю, через что это вообще делается в ларавеле. Откуда начинать гуглить.

Comment: В этой же статье ссылка на библиотеку https://github.com/hflabs/dadata-php

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/184302/ статейка про keep-alive соединения в PHP

Comment: То есть, ПРОСТО подключить библиотеку и пользоваться?

Comment: Посмотрел статью, это мне знакомо. Как переиспользовать коннект в рамкахх одного запроса клиента, я знаю. У меня проблема в том, что клиенты разные. Допустим, есть 100 операторов, которые за разными ПК делают запросы к моему серверу "дай подсказку". Сервер для каждого такого запроса создаёт новый процесс, который и пинает внешний сервис отдельным запросом. А нужно, чтобы все эти запросы использовали один процесс на моём сервере, и тогда будет один коннект.

Comment: По словам разработчиков сервиса, библиотека как раз и должна решить этот вопрос

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: @lezhni по словам разработчиков, имеется ввиду поддержание соединения в рамках одного запроса

Comment: Ну, PHP так работает - один запрос на сервер это один отдельный процесс, по другому значит и не получится